# Is there a 'process algebra' to describe ACID transactions on a database?

Tags: algebra, process-algebra

There appears to be this [beautiful algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model_and_process_calculi) to help you think through the implications of Communicating Sequential Processes by Hoare.

What I'm wondering, is there an equivalent algebra that helps you think through ACID transactions on a database, where one suceeds and another rolls back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [paper](http://alexandria.tue.nl/extra1/wskrap/public_html/200218.pdf) by Van Beek called *An Algebraic Approach to Transactional Processes* which describes adding transactions to process algebra:

```
(a :~ 0 . a:~ a + 2) II (a:~ 1 a:~ a X 2) ((a :~ 0 . a:~ a + 2)) II ((a:~ 1 a:~ a X 2))
```

This paper even delves into isolation levels.

The author describes how in Communicating Sequential Processes (CSP), if you have a write blocked on a read, you can get into a deadlock scenario.

The author references another paper *J.A. Bergstra, A. Ponse, and J.J. van Warne. Process algebra with backtracking* which allows for rollback of a failed CSP operation.

There is discussion on the nature of transactions in *K.P. Eswaran, J .N. Gray, R.A. Lorie, and 1.1. Traiger. On the notions of consistency and  predicate locks in a data base system. Communications of the ACM, 19(11)*

The properties of transactions are described in *] J. Gray and A. Reuter. Transaction Processing: Concepts and Techniques.*

The acid properties of transactions are described in *J. Gray. The transaction concept: Virtues and limitations* and in *T. Haerder and A. Reuter. Principles of transaction-oriented database recovery*